# Why is the image not blinking when Status Bar is expanded?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I have a method to make the icon blink in the status bar that takes image from a level list. The image blinks when the status bar is not expanded. But this image does not blink when the status bar is expanded (i.e. in the status window). Am I missing something?

```
private void startIconBlink(final int notificationId, Notification notifyDetails, final String notificationTimestamp)
{
    notifyDetails.defaults = 0;
    final Notification notification = notifyDetails;
    new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            int i = 0;
            try{
                while(i < 30)
                {
                    //If notification has been raised again, then stop this thread.
                    if(!(notificationIdHashTable.get(notificationId + "").equals(notificationTimestamp)))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if(i%2 == 0)
                    {
                        notification.iconLevel = 0;
                        //
                    }
                    else {
                        notification.iconLevel = 1;
                        //mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
                    }

                    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);

                    i++;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

This is the level list file:

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/alert1" />
<item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/alert2" />
```

I am setting it to the notification bar from here:

```
int imageIcon=R.drawable.level_list ;
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_layout);
                notifyDetails.contentView = contentView;
                notifyDetails.contentIntent = myIntent;
                notifyDetails.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title,messageTitle);
                notifyDetails.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
                notifyDetails.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, imageIcon);
```